# Vue SPA with Laravel Backend End-To-End Testing

Tags: laravel, testing, integration-testing

I have two separate projects, a Vue SPA and a Laravel backend.

Now, I would like to write some end-to-end tests from our Vue SPA to our Laravel backend. I would like to write SPA tests which make real backend API calls. But the Laravel API should know that this are testing calls and handle them like when running tests with phpunit. So this calls should use the .env.testing or the phpunit.xml env settings, e.g. use the testing database and testing mail provider.

So is there a possibility to tell Laravel, that it should handle a request with env = testing?

I've found an old [article from Mohamed Said](https://m.dotdev.co/acceptance-testing-a-laravel-and-vue-js-application-4160b8e96156) which goes in this direction, with setting a cookie. But I hope there is an easier way, especially with loading the whole .env.testing variables?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How about pointing the vue app at a testing API URL for the e2e tests, then the testing API can just use a test database and mail settings permanently?

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works: 
I create a new subdomain with a special nginx param:

```
fastcgi_param TESTING_DOMAIN TRUE;
```

In Laravel Homestead, this can easily be done within the Homestead.yaml:

```
    -   map: testing.mydomain.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/mydomain/public
        schedule: true
        backup: false
        php: "7.4"
        params:
            - key: TESTING_DOMAIN
              value: "TRUE"
```

Then in Laravel, I added this in the bootstrap/app.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Loading environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is project specific, loading .env.testing on testing domains, if:
| fastcgi_param TESTING_DOMAIN TRUE;
|
*/
if ($_SERVER["TESTING_DOMAIN"] ?? null) {
    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
}
```

Then I can make a call to testing.mydomain.test and it works:

```
ddd(\App::environment()); // => "testing" - from .env.testing
```

I get now all environment variables from .env.testing.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Laravel Dusk?
That way you can define .env.dusk.{environment} to override any env variables. Makes everything much simpler and is a joy to use.

Comment: Use Laravel Dusk with a Vue SPA, I don't thinkt this is possible, is it? My Goal is to write end-to-end tests from the Vue SPA down to the backend in one line.

Comment: @ndberg Indeed it is!
I was initially using NightWatch in my project but then discovered Dusk does work with SPAs. A more seamless experience than NW as you are whithin the framework. Also has most of the concepts from js E2E framworks like pages and components for reuasbility. You don't even need to install any browser drivers!

Comment: oh ok thanks, I'll give it a try.